# obligatory element in xml using xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

for attribute we will be using use

but what about xs:element  minoccurs is the only way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to write "In short, yes." but Stack Overflow gave me the error "body must be at least 30 characters". I wonder why simple answers are not allowed...

Comment: sry.. and i would like to have a xsd:element to be obligatory and i already know that for xs:attribute i am using 'use' in order to specify whether it is optional or mandatory .. how can we do that when we are dealing with an xs:element (in an example they used minOccurs=1.. Is that the only solution)..

Comment: `minOccurs="1"` is the solution. There is no `use` attribute for `xs:element`. The default value for `minOccurs` is 1 so just defining an element without a `minOccurs` attribute also makes the element obligatory (in the containing sequence).